# Application crashes when using Android NDK+pthreads

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash, pthreads

I need to write a simple program which measures execution time of doing matrix multiplication implemented with NDK+pthreads. Unfortunately, an application crashes as soon as calculation is requested. There is no message in logcat and no dialogue window like "Your app has crashed". Below is the fragment of code in which crash might happen:

```
... //Include headers, declare variables and stuff like that

void* calculate_row(void* row)
{
    int x = *((int *) row);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        C[x][i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            C[x][i] += A[x][j]*B[j][i];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

jdouble Java_com_example_avl_ndktest_Main_calculateProductTime(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint a)
{

    ... //Initializing and so on

    clock_t startTime = clock();
    pthread_t *threads = (pthread_t*) malloc(n*sizeof(pthread_t));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, calculate_row, (void *) &i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    clock_t elapsedTime = (clock()-startTime);
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);
    free(threads);
    return (double) (elapsedTime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

Please note that non-pthread version does not crash and works properly. Also, these threads don't interact with VM, so I didn't bind them to it. I will appreciate any kind of help with my issue.

UPDATE
The problem can be solved by changing

```
pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, calculate_row, (void *) &i);
```

to

```
pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, calculate_row, (void *) i);
```

and

```
int x = *((int *) row);
```

to

```
int x = (int *) row;
```

It seems like at the time of initializing x, the value of i might have become inadequate and retrieving this value by address must have caused the crash, because x was out of bounds.

Comment: Add log messages between every two lines.  That'll tell you how far it gets before vanishing.  One popular way to crash without a crash report is to overflow the native stack (which causes the crash-handler to fault unless an alt signal stack is provided), but there's nothing in your code to suggest that as the problem.  FWIW, used a similar program to poke at the CPU core scheduler: http://bigflake.com/cpu-spinner.c.txt

Comment: Using logs helped, the problem was pretty hard to notice - the argument passed to function was not i, but &i, which is the address, this caused x to have inadequate values (which were located at i's address) and crash the app. I wonder why there were no messages, because it seems to be a plain segmentation fault from having an array index out of bounds. Thanks for helping!